# eslint erroring on es6 when .js files, fine for .jsx files

Tags: lint, eslint

error: **Parsing error: Unexpected token ..**

My lint gulp task is giving me issues on '.js' files, while '.jsx' are doing fine on ES6 syntax.

Notably, the "..." operator - for spread/rest etc.

Is there a way to get this to work? Here is part of my config. (I tried adding ".js: true", didn't help)

```
{  
    "parser":"espree",
    "ecmaFeatures":{  
        "modules":true,
        "jsx":true
    },
```

Comment: what version of eslint are you using?

Comment: "gulp-eslint": "^1.1.1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to enable the [`experimentalObjectRestSpread` parser option](http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring.html#specifying-parser-options):

```
{
    "ecmaFeatures": {
        "experimentalObjectRestSpread": true,
        "jsx": true,
        "modules": true
    }
}
```

Since Espree is already the default parser, you don't need to specify it unless you want to for clarity's sake.